# Scroll, css and vue problems

Tags: css, vue.js

I am really new to this topic, but I am working with vue and css, I made a responsive menu but now what is difficult for me is to put a Scroll ONLY to the drop-down menu

the problem I have is that when I scroll, my whole page moves and this is not correct, I just have to drop the menu and not my whole page

[image]

As you can see in the image, only what is in the red rectangle (Menu) I want to scroll, searching the web I have not managed to make it work

```css
@media (max-width: 828px) {
    #menu-header.show {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        -ms-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    #accordion-mbl-menu {
        margin: 0;
        .panel {
            box-shadow: none !important;
            background-color: transparent;
            border-radius: 0;
            border: 0;
            margin-bottom: 0;
            >button.collapsed {
                color: #001e50;
                >.icon {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
                    transform: rotate(0deg);
                }
            }
            >button.not-collapsed>.icon {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
                transform: rotate(180deg);
            }
            >button {
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
                width: 100%;
                height: 55px;
                font-size: 20px;
                font-family: "VWHead-Bold";
                font-weight: normal;
                color: #2f3538;
                text-decoration: none;
                outline: none !important;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #dee1e3;
                padding-right: 15px;
                position: relative;
                display: -webkit-box;
                display: -webkit-flex;
                display: -moz-box;
                display: -ms-flexbox;
                display: flex;
                -webkit-box-align: center;
                -webkit-align-items: center;
                -moz-box-align: center;
                -ms-flex-align: center;
                align-items: center;
                >.icon {
                    width: 20px;
                    height: 20px;
                    fill: currentColor;
                    -webkit-transition: all 350ms ease;
                    transition: all 350ms ease;
                    position: absolute;
                    right: 15px;
                    top: auto;
                }
                .collapse.in {
                    display: block;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .login-section {
        height: 36px;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 56px;
        width: 100%;
        a {
            font-family: "VWText-Regular";
            color: #000000;
            font-size: 14px;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            img.icon {
                position: relative;
                top: -5px;
                width: 24px;
                height: 24px;
            }
            .text-account {
                padding-left: 5px;
                position: relative;
                top: 2px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My code VUE

```
<div id="menu-mobile-cats" class="scrollbar-outer scroll-content scroll-scrolly_visible">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion-mbl-menu">
      <div class="panel">
        <b-navbar-toggle target="collapse-cat-lvl1-469">
          Accesorios
          <img src="@/assets/images/layout/menu/chevron.svg" class="icon">
        </b-navbar-toggle>
        <div style="background-color:white;">
          <b-collapse id="collapse-cat-lvl1-469">
            <div data-cat-acc="473" class="grid-item parent-lvl-2">
              <a class="link -1 grid-sty-1" href="#" target="_self" data-menu-item-id="473">
                <span class="text">GTI</span>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div data-cat-acc="474" class="grid-item parent-lvl-2">
              <a class="link sty-1 grid-sty-1" href="#" target="_self" data-menu-item-id="474">
                <span class="text">Pets</span>
              </a>
            </div>
```

If someone can tell me where to take an example or help me do it, as I mentioned I am something new in this

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include the rendered HTML and rendered CSS. Without your HTML, this is really hard to debug. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Set `{overflow-y: scroll;}` to the **parent** of the `list` and give it a *specific* `height`. 
You can play with the `var times` to *add* or *remove* `li`'s for testing. 
The scroll bar is hidden - you can customize it to fit well on smaller devices

```js
// get the list
var list = document.getElementById("list");
// Array to hold HTML output
var output = [];
// Add and remove "li" for testing
var times = 15;

for (let x = 0; x < times; x++){
  let item = `<li><a href="#">Text</a></li>`;
  output.push(item);
}

list.innerHTML = output.join('');
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.wrapper > ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

.wrapper > ul > li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul id="list"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really occupy ul .. already add the code segment that I use to implement my menu with VUE.JS..... How could I implement this with my code?